# BIOS Bootlop with more than one core active i7-8700k

Tags: cpu, bios

Some time ago I found used i7-8700k with unknown condition for cheap. Seller tells me that the processor itself works, however only with one core active in BIOS, whenever he switches to all cores it is going into bootloop. Is it related to some software/BIOS problem or is it hardware failure and there's nothing that can be done about it?

Comment: Can you return it?  It sounds more broken than healthy.

Comment: It could be hardware failure and it can also be incorrectly set settings in bios. If you own the processor right now, try underclocking it, all cores active but low speeds and low voltages. The cpu will not get too hot and may possibly work well with all cores enabled, just not on the specs it should run. But maybe it can work on this. Who knows....

Comment: @John I haven't bought it yet, that's why I'm asking

Comment: I would say do not purchase it. From your description, it will not be worth the hassle.

Comment: @LPChip I didn't get my hands on it yet, I'm asking if it's even worth trying with this chip. It costs about $90

Comment: I wouldn't bother then. May be a good chip, but with a description like that, if its really a hardware problem, it'll bring you more harm than good in the long run anyway.

Comment: That's good to know, I thought so smh, gonna wait for couple more opinions on that, but I guess I'll pass on this.